# Select from table with date as reference

Tags: mysql, sql, select

so I'm having trouble with a SELECT statement.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee 
( 
    EmployeeID         NVARCHAR(4000), 
    Name                NVARCHAR(200) 
); 

CREATE TABLE Promotion 
( 
    PromotionID         NVARCHAR(4000), 
    EmployeeID           NVARCHAR(4000),
    Date                    Date
); 


INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeID, Name) VALUES ('12345', 'Sam'); 
INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeID, Name) VALUES ('13335', 'Tom'); 


INSERT INTO Promotion (PromotionID, EmployeeID, Date) VALUES ('1', '12345', '2019-05-20'); 
INSERT INTO Promotion (PromotionID, EmployeeID, Date) VALUES ('2', '12345', '2020-08-27'); 
INSERT INTO Promotion (PromotionID, EmployeeID, Date) VALUES ('2', '13335', '2020-06-27');
```

These are the two tables I want to select from.

So what I need is a selection, where I get the PromotionID at the latest date for every unique EmployeeID if that makes sense :D.

It should look like:

```
PromotionID EmployeeID    Date        Name

2           12345         2020-08-27  Sam
2           13335         2020-06-27  Tom
```

So what i got until now is

```
SELECT p.EmployeeID, max(p.Date)
FROM Promotion p
JOIN Employee e on p.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID 
Group BY p.EmployeeID
```

What gives me

```
EmployeeID      Date

12345           2020-08-27
13335           2020-06-27
```

But i can't figure it out. I just don't get the PromotionID in connection with the latest date.

I'd appreciate some help.

Thank you

Tom

Here starts the edit.

```
INSERT INTO Promotion (PromotionID, EmployeeID, Date) VALUES ('PA', '12345', '2019-05-20'); 
INSERT INTO Promotion (PromotionID, EmployeeID, Date) VALUES ('MA', '12345', '2020-08-27'); 
INSERT INTO Promotion (PromotionID, EmployeeID, Date) VALUES ('CO', '13335', '2020-06-27'); 
INSERT INTO Promotion (PromotionID, EmployeeID, Date) VALUES ('AI', '15555', '2020-01-18'); 
INSERT INTO Promotion (PromotionID, EmployeeID, Date) VALUES ('CO', '12345', '2021-05-20');
```

This are the new entries for the table.

[This is what I get as a result when I use @Tim Biegeleisen code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLqLV.png)

From the system itself, there can't be more than one promotion for one person at on date. If this helps.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't get"? You haven't selected that specific column

Comment: Version 5.5 I think.

Comment: I didn't select the column because it's not that easy with my small knowladge of SQL to get it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the old-fashioned way of doing this in MySQL:

```
SELECT
    e.EmployeeId,
    e.Name,
    p1.PromotionID,
    p1.Date
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Promotion p1
    ON e.EmployeeId = p1.EmployeeId
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT EmployeeId, MAX(Date) AS max_date
    FROM Promotion
    GROUP BY EmployeeId
) p2
    ON p1.EmployeeId = p2.EmployeeId AND
       p1.Date = p2.max_date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you. This works well but it prints all of the promotions but I only need the promotions of every employee with the latest dates. So max. one promotion per employee displayed.

Comment: @tom18192 I disagree, and my query is working correctly, at least for the small set of sample data you provided (and thanks for the DDL by the way).

Comment: @tom, This should not print multiple records for the same employee, unless you have multiple records on the same date for the same employee in the data

Comment: Thank you guys for all the help. A little update on the table itself. The promotionID is not a number but a set of two characters like (PM, SM, CO,...) (Sorry i got that wrong). I added a few more entries with different dates to the table. I put an example on how it looks like in the post.

Comment: Nvm. I see you edited the code, now it works perfactly thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already have most of it. Assuming that the promotion id follows a sequential order by date, You can just take a max of promotion id to do this:

```
SELECT p.EmployeeID,e.name, max(p.Date) as date, max(p.PromotionID) as PromotionID
FROM Promotion p
JOIN Employee e on p.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID 
Group BY p.EmployeeID,e.name
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There may not be a guarantee that the max `PromotionId` will correlate with the max date (although it might be likely).

Comment: That's true...I will add it as a disclaimer...Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Thanks for the help but in fact if i change the PromotionID it not works quite right

Comment: Seems to be providing the expected result for the sample set...If it is failing for different records, it would make it easier if you can share those cases and the results you are getting